# How to write module in ECMAScript 6

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

The below code is working with `nodejs 4.4`:

```
"use strict";

const test = (res) => {
    return (data) => {
        return res.json({"message": "testing"});
    };
};

module.exports = test;
```

My question is using `const` correct, or is it correctly written using `ES6`?

Comment: Do you want a node (commonjs) module or an ES6 module?

Comment: @Bergi any different, the plan is to write a node module that can be distribute through NPM.

Comment: Yes, it's different, but for a node currently the commonjs syntax is fine.

Comment: Why use `const test` at all? Just assign the function expression directly to `module.exports`. But no, it's not wrong to introduce an additional variable, and not to make that variable constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `const` like that. `const` means "the value of this variable cannot be changed" and the interpreter will complain if you try to assign a new value to it.

Is the code above "correctly written using ES6"? Depends what you mean... for example, ES6 uses `export` instead of `module.exports`, but what you've written is not *wrong*. After all, it works.

ES6 is not a different language - it's Javascript with some new features. It's up to you to decide how many of those features you want to use.

Comment: how can I use export?

Comment: Try googling "es6 export". There are lots of resources out there about the new import/export syntax